# Select Group by Month

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT dataVen, Sum(valorTotal) as valorTotal FROM cad_cr2 Group by MONTH(dataVen)
```

A consulta acima retorna os seguintes valores:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Desejo é que ficasse assim, agrupado por mês:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já fiz várias pesquisas e tentativas, porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Não bastaria fazer `select month(dataVen)`?

Comment: Cuidado com mesmo mês de anos diferentes. Sugiro que utilize mês/ano na exibição e no agrupamento.

Answer (score 2):

Basta inserir `MONTH` no `SELECT`, fica assim:

```
SELECT MONTH(dataVen), SUM(valorTotal) AS valorTotal 
  FROM cad_cr2 GROUP BY MONTH(dataVen)
```

Answer (score 1):

A função `MONTH(data)` recebe uma data como parâmetro e te retorna o mês da data informada.

Você já está agrupando sua consulta pelo mês e está somando os valores agrupados, agora só falta você mostrar o mês no seu `SELECT`:

```
SELECT MONTH(dataVen), 
       SUM(valorTotal) as valorTotal 
  FROM cad_cr2 
 GROUP BY MONTH(dataVen)
```

**Observação:** A sua consulta está sendo agrupada somente pelo mês da data de vencimento `(dataVen)`, sendo assim você está agrupando mesmo que os anos sejam diferentes. Exemplo:

> **dataVen**   ..................... **valorTotal**
>
> 20/10/2005 ................. 5
>
> 05/10/2018 ................. 10
>
> 09/10/2018 ................. 15

Nesse caso o seu retorno vai ser:

> **dataVen**   ..................... **valorTotal**
>
> 10 ................. 30

Não sei da sua regra de negócio, mas estou deixando a dica pois imagino que você queira filtrar apenas pelo ano atual.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar o `MONTH()` ou `DATE_FORMAT(dataVen, '%m')`. Se você quer extrair só o Mês, Ano ou Dia o MySQL já tem funções próprias para isso:

> `DAY(data) = para dia`
>
> `MONTH(data) = para mes`
>
> `YEAR(data) = para ano`

```
SELECT MONTH(dataVen), SUM(valorTotal) AS valorTotal 
  FROM cad_cr2 GROUP BY MONTH(dataVen)
```

---

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dataVen, '%m'), SUM(valorTotal) AS valorTotal 
  FROM cad_cr2 GROUP BY MONTH(dataVen)
```